# Loading a page in jQuery without page load

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

As we know that react doesn't load the window on click of an anchor. That's why react web apps are fast. I want the same functionality in jQuery. I want to Load a page in Jquery Without Loading the head, header, and footer. How can I do it? I don't know if I can even do it or not.

```js
  $(document).on("click", function (e) {
    let anchor = $(e.target);
    var url = anchor.attr("data-url-redirect");
    if (e.target.nodeName == "A") {
      // console.log(anchor, url);

      $.ajax({
        url: url + '.html',
        success: function (result) {
          $(".pageWrapper").html(result);
          console.log(result, url);

          if (history.pushState) {
            var newurl =
              window.location.protocol +
              `//` +
              window.location.host +
              window.location.pathname +
              "/" +
              url;
            window.history.pushState({ path: newurl }, "", newurl);
          }
        },
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This is the code I wrote. I can load the page and change the URL. But when I refresh the page breaks. Please let me know if it is possible with jQuery or not. If it is possible then how can I achieve it?